# Why does BACKSPACE generate C-h?

Tags: key-bindings, help, backspace

When running emacs (v29.1) -nw on a ThinkPad X61 under FreeBSD 13.2, pressing Backspace generates C-h. The key is not bound to anything.
Running C-h k BACKSPACE does not show DEL but C-h-h. Entering BACKSPACE again shows C-h C-h.

BACKSPACE behaves normally outside of emacs.

What can I do so that emacs interprets BACKSPACE properly?

Comment: Does the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/DEL-Does-Not-Delete.html) help?

Comment: Put this in your init file "(normal-erase-is-backspace-mode 1)".  See: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/DEL-Does-Not-Delete.html#DEL-Does-Not-Delete

Answer (score 2):

This answers the question posed in your question *title*:

In a nutshell: the ASCII control character Control-H has been called `BACKSPACE`.

`C-q C-h` inserts a Control-H character. Then `C-u C-x =` just before that char in the buffer tells us that the "old name" is `BACKSPACE`:

```
             position: 147 of 147 (99%), column: 0
            character:
                       C-h (displayed as C-h) (codepoint 8, #o10, #x8)
    preferred charset: ascii (ASCII (ISO646 IRV))
code point in charset: 0x08
               script: latin
               syntax: _    which means: symbol
             to input: type "C-x 8 RET 8" or "C-x 8 RET BACKSPACE"
          buffer code: #x08
            file code: #x08
                       (encoded by coding system iso-latin-1-unix)
              display: no font available
       hardcoded face: escape-glyph

Character code properties: customize what to show
  old-name: BACKSPACE
  general-category: Cc (Other, Control)

There are text properties here:
  fontified            t
```

See also:

- Wikipedia [Backspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backspace)
- Wikipedia [Control Character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character)

---

This answers the *different* question posed in your question body:

From the Emacs manual, node [If DEL Fails to Delete](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/DEL-Does-Not-Delete.html), tells us:

> customize the variable `normal-erase-is-backspace`: the value `t` specifies the mode where `BS` or `BACKSPACE` is `DEL`, and `nil` specifies the other mode.

`M-x customize-option normal-erase-is-backspace`

Comment: Changing this variable turns C-h into BACKSPACE. It is not a usable solution. In addition, if I ssh into a system i also need to change the variable in init.el on that system, but only for a particular system logging in.

Comment: Did you use `M-x customize-option normal-erase-is-backspace`, then choose the value you want in the `Value Menu`, and then choose `Save for Future Sessions` from the `State` menu?